In meson, how do you use an exe produced by a subproject in a custom_target() declaration?
I have a project proj that depends on a subproject mygen, which produces an executable, mygen_exe. proj depends on this executable. If mygen was not built by mygen, but installed then I would do:
mygen = find_program('mygen_exe')
my_src = custom_target('gen-output',
  output : [...],
  input : 'input.mygen',
  command : [mygen, '-o', '@OUTDIR@', '--for-cpp', '@INPUT@'],
  )

However this does not work if mygen_exe is created by a subproject. So my question is how can I write a custom_target that depends on a command (mygen_exe) created by a subproject?
